# How to fix IntelliSense: expression must have pointer-to-object type in MFC?

Tags: c++, mfc

I have define an `sUart` as `0` to my code: (`Sample`)

This was the error:

[image]

```
// MFCApplication2Dlg.cpp : implementation file
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "MFCApplication2.h"
#include "MFCApplication2Dlg.h"
#include "afxdialogex.h"
#include "afxwin.h"
#include "CyAPI.h"
#include "Periph.h"
#include "Resource.h"
#include "UART.h"

#define sUart 0

#ifdef _DEBUG
#define new DEBUG_NEW
#endif

bool IsConnect = false;
// CAboutDlg dialog used for App About

class CAboutDlg : public CDialogEx
{
public:
    CAboutDlg();

// Dialog Data
    enum { IDD = IDD_ABOUTBOX };

    protected:
    virtual void DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX);    // DDX/DDV support

// Implementation
protected:
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
};

CAboutDlg::CAboutDlg() : CDialogEx(CAboutDlg::IDD)
{
}

void CAboutDlg::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CDialogEx::DoDataExchange(pDX);
}

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CAboutDlg, CDialogEx)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()


// CMFCApplication2Dlg dialog



CMFCApplication2Dlg::CMFCApplication2Dlg(CWnd* pParent /*=NULL*/)
    : CDialogEx(CMFCApplication2Dlg::IDD, pParent)
{
    m_hIcon = AfxGetApp()->LoadIcon(IDR_MAINFRAME);
}

void CMFCApplication2Dlg::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CDialogEx::DoDataExchange(pDX);
}

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMFCApplication2Dlg, CDialogEx)
    ON_WM_SYSCOMMAND()
    ON_WM_PAINT()
    ON_WM_QUERYDRAGICON()
    ON_BN_CLICKED(IDC_BUTTON1, &CMFCApplication2Dlg::OnBnClickedButton1)
    ON_BN_CLICKED(IDC_BUTTON2, &CMFCApplication2Dlg::OnBnClickedButton2)
    ON_BN_CLICKED(IDC_BUTTON3, &CMFCApplication2Dlg::OnBnClickedButton3)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()


// CMFCApplication2Dlg message handlers

BOOL CMFCApplication2Dlg::OnInitDialog()
{
    CDialogEx::OnInitDialog();

    // Add "About..." menu item to system menu.

    // IDM_ABOUTBOX must be in the system command range.
    ASSERT((IDM_ABOUTBOX & 0xFFF0) == IDM_ABOUTBOX);
    ASSERT(IDM_ABOUTBOX < 0xF000);

    CMenu* pSysMenu = GetSystemMenu(FALSE);
    if (pSysMenu != NULL)
    {
        BOOL bNameValid;
        CString strAboutMenu;
        bNameValid = strAboutMenu.LoadString(IDS_ABOUTBOX);
        ASSERT(bNameValid);
        if (!strAboutMenu.IsEmpty())
        {
            pSysMenu->AppendMenu(MF_SEPARATOR);
            pSysMenu->AppendMenu(MF_STRING, IDM_ABOUTBOX, strAboutMenu);
        }
    }

    // Set the icon for this dialog.  The framework does this automatically
    //  when the application's main window is not a dialog
    SetIcon(m_hIcon, TRUE);         // Set big icon
    SetIcon(m_hIcon, FALSE);        // Set small icon

    // TODO: Add extra initialization here

    return TRUE;  // return TRUE  unless you set the focus to a control
}

void CMFCApplication2Dlg::OnSysCommand(UINT nID, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if ((nID & 0xFFF0) == IDM_ABOUTBOX)
    {
        CAboutDlg dlgAbout;
        dlgAbout.DoModal();
    }
    else
    {
        CDialogEx::OnSysCommand(nID, lParam);
    }
}

// If you add a minimize button to your dialog, you will need the code below
//  to draw the icon.  For MFC applications using the document/view model,
//  this is automatically done for you by the framework.

void CMFCApplication2Dlg::OnPaint()
{
    if (IsIconic())
    {
        CPaintDC dc(this); // device context for painting

        SendMessage(WM_ICONERASEBKGND, reinterpret_cast<WPARAM>(dc.GetSafeHdc()), 0);

        // Center icon in client rectangle
        int cxIcon = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXICON);
        int cyIcon = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYICON);
        CRect rect;
        GetClientRect(&rect);
        int x = (rect.Width() - cxIcon + 1) / 2;
        int y = (rect.Height() - cyIcon + 1) / 2;

        // Draw the icon
        dc.DrawIcon(x, y, m_hIcon);
    }
    else
    {
        CDialogEx::OnPaint();
    }
}

// The system calls this function to obtain the cursor to display while the user drags
//  the minimized window.
HCURSOR CMFCApplication2Dlg::OnQueryDragIcon()
{
    return static_cast<HCURSOR>(m_hIcon);
}


void CMFCApplication2Dlg::OnBnClickedButton1()
{

    USBDevice->Open(0);

    if (USBDevice->IsOpen() != TRUE)
    {
        AfxMessageBox(_T("Failed to Open Device"));
    }
    else
    {
        IsConnect = true;
    }
}


void CMFCApplication2Dlg::OnBnClickedButton3()
{
    USBDevice->Close();
    IsConnect = false;
}

void CMFCApplication2Dlg::OnBnClickedButton2()
{
    TCHAR tmpUart[60];
    long OutPacketSize;
    OutPacketSize = sizeof(sUart);

    LPTSTR pBuffer;
    CString sBuffer;

    int i;

    if (IsConnect == false)
    {
        AfxMessageBox(_T("USB Connect Fail"));
        return;
    }

    CEdit *OutValue = (CEdit*)GetDlgItem(IDC_OUT_VALUE);

    pBuffer = sBuffer.GetBuffer(60);
    OutValue->GetWindowText(pBuffer, 60);

    _tcscpy(tmpUart, pBuffer);

    OutPacketSize = _tcslen(tmpUart);

    for (i = 0; i<OutPacketSize; i++) sUart[i] = tmpUart[i];

    sUart[OutPacketSize + 1] = 0;
    OutPacketSize = OutPacketSize + 1;

    // Perform the BULK OUT

    if (USBDevice->BulkOutEndPt)
    {
        USBDevice->BulkOutEndPt->XferData(sUart, OutPacketSize);
    }

}
```

Is there a way to to fix this intellisense to change the expression to have a pointer-to-object type to accurately fix this error? Please I really need help, I'm new to (***Microsoft-Foundation-Classes***).

Answer (score 2):

The variable `sUart` is defined as

```
#define sUart 0
```

Then you try to assign to it as if it were an array

```
for (i = 0; i<OutPacketSize; i++)
    sUart[i] = tmpUart[i];
```

If you are expecting `sUart` to be an array of `TCHAR` then you should declare it as such

```
TCHAR* sUart = nullptr;
```

Also you never appear to actually allocate any memory for this array (using `new[]`/`delete[]`).

Comment: Could you provide a best solution to this code sir?? the `#define sUart 0` is only just a sample for me. Please, thanks.

Comment: do you know how to fix this?